# REST API-server dilemma

Tags: node.js, api, rest, meteor

I plan to build a server that will use a REST API on NODE.JS with Meteor.

What are the differences between these two methods of writing an API:

1.http://meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API
example: someSrver.com/**post/:_id**

2. someSrver.com/**post?id=_id**

Thanks

Comment: Read also http://jsonapi.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no really difference at least you are handling request correctly.
I think the second style suit better if you have to pass server a lot of parameters for example a service that provide high res image, where you can specify tile size, coordinates and other things like that. 
If you use api as an interface to database usually first style is used.

I've develop a rest interface using this library: https://atmospherejs.com/nimble/restivus , it's very easy to use and it use first style.

Answer (score 0):

So, you should read up on REST principles and API design if you want to really understand the why's.

But generally, the rule of thumb is that a URL should represent a resource.  The paths generally represent a given "thing" and the querystring represents some kind of filter on that "thing".

So if you "post" object is logically its own entity (e.g.a  blog post), then it'd have its own unique url such that a GET to www.example.com/posts/:id would return the one specific blog entry you're talking about.

GET /posts would map to a list of all posts, for  example, and GET /posts?tagged=cheetahs would get you a list of all posts filtered to return just those with the tag of 'cheetahs' assigned to them.

This is all rules of thumb and standards.  The implementation really doesn't matter and most servers don't care; but there is value in following the standards as they tend to be more maintainable, elegant, and help you not have to make a million design decisions.  If you ever want others to integrate with you, it makes it easier for them to know what to expect as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the URI standard, the query is for non-hierarchical filters while, the path is for hierarchical ones.

I would use query if we are talking about a filtered collection, so the result will be a representation of a collection, for example json `[]`. On the other hand if we are talking about an item, then I would use the path and the json would be an object/item `{}`. But this is only my own style, you can use which one you prefer. (The URI structure has only routing purposes if you use REST with HATEOAS. I assume you don't.)

Answer (score 0):

In REST the URL/URI is the address of an item or a collection of items. So, to get all addresses for customer 2 you could do this:

```
/api/customer/2/addresses
```

If however you wanted just those addresses with a postcode you could go:

```
/api/customer/2/addresses?withPostcode=1
```

In this case, the first URL/URI represents a thing/things whereas the second has a modifier, restriction or filter applied to it.

Therefore `someSrver.com/post/:_id` means get me the post *which is known by that ID* (though ideally it would be `someSrver.com/posts/:_id` - note the plural). Whereas the second one (`someSrver.com/post?id=_id`) implies that everything to the left of the question mark has *already* narrowed down your thing/things and they now need filtering by an ID *property* (in this case) on the thing.

It's a subtle distinction in many cases, but I'd sum it up as the first applying a selector/location and the second applying a selector/location with a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't implement REST API server in node yet, I want to share with you few important points when you design your server:

- Try to use flat paths for the controllers, nested paths are causing confusion.
- Avoid custom HTTP methods such as PUT, HEAD and PATCH, not all firewalls like them.
- Use applicative error codes with HTTP 200 OK and use the HTTP protocol error codes only for HTTP errors.

See more: http://restafar.com/create-new-rest-server/